# Pivot on two aggregate fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Hi thanks for any help

Gerry

How do I pivot on LAVG and Patient for the months. Example

```
Facility Jan Feb Mar ect

Downey   30  25  28

Downey   10  9   8
```

I know this doesn't work but this is what I what to do

> PIVOT (SUM(LAVG), Count(Patient) FOR months IN (jan, feb, mar ect

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Spoclos]
  -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  @Year      INT,
  @PayerCode VARCHAR(3),
  @ID        INT
AS
  BEGIN
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
      -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      -- Insert statements for procedure here
      SELECT *
      FROM   (SELECT LEFT(Months, 3) AS Months,
                     FacilityName,
                     LAVG,
                     Patient,
                     Region,
                     ID,
                     payercode,
                     facilityCode
              FROM   dbo.LOSGroup
              WHERE  PayerCode = @PayerCode
                     AND years = @year
                     AND ID = @id) AS s
             PIVOT (Sum(LAVG)
                   FOR months IN (jan,feb,mar,apr,
                        may,jun,jul,aug,
                        sep,oct,nov,dec)) AS piv
      ORDER  BY ID
  END
```

Comment: what SQL variant is that?

Comment: Am tagging `Sql Server` since the syntax looks like sql server

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned you cannot have two `Aggregate` functions inside pivot.

Have two separate `Pivot` queries one to find `Sum` and another to find `Count`. Then use Union All to Combine the result.

```
SELECT 'Sum' [Aggregate],*
FROM   (SELECT LEFT(Months, 3) AS Months,
               FacilityName,LAVG,Patient,
               Region,ID,payercode,
               facilityCode
        FROM   dbo.LOSGroup
        WHERE  PayerCode = @PayerCode
               AND years = @year
               AND ID = @id) AS s
       PIVOT (Sum(LAVG)
             FOR months IN (jan,feb,mar,apr,
                            may,jun,jul,aug,
                            sep,oct,nov,dec)) AS piv
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Count' [Aggregate],*
FROM   (SELECT LEFT(Months, 3) AS Months,
               FacilityName,LAVG,Patient,
               Region,ID,payercode,
               facilityCode
        FROM   dbo.LOSGroup
        WHERE  PayerCode = @PayerCode
               AND years = @year
               AND ID = @id) AS s
       PIVOT (Count(LAVG)
             FOR months IN (jan,feb,mar,apr,
                            may,jun,jul,aug,
                            sep,oct,nov,dec)) AS piv
ORDER  BY ID
```

**Note:** To differentiate the `Sum` and `Count` I have used a extra column `Aggregate`